# output variables from doctrine in twig

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

Im new to symfony and what im trying is next:

1. Select everything from the table and count the number of rows.
2. Access and display this informations in a twig template.

This is part from my code in the controler dedicated to fetch data from datatabase :

```
 .
 .
 .
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $query=$em->createQuery('SELECT b,COUNT(b.id) FROM AcmeWebBundle:baza b ORDER BY b.id DESC');
    $users = $query->getResult();
    if (!$em) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Something went wrong!');

    }
    return $this->render('AcmeWebBundle:Default:index.html.twig',array('users'=>$users));
}
```

in the table named baza i have the fields: id,username,date..etc

And part from the twig file named index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'AcmeWebBundle:Default:master.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<h1> something</h1><br></br>
{% for user in users %}

{{ ...how to access to the number of rows and other data...}}

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: number of row: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/length.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder()
          ->from('AcmeWebBundle:baza', 'b')
          ->getQuery();

$user = $query->select('b')
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult();

$total = $query->select('COUNT(b)')
           ->getQuery()
           ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

.....

```
return $this->render('AcmeWebBundle:Default:index.html.twig',array('users' => $users, 'count' => $total));
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'AcmeWebBundle:Default:master.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
  <h1> something</h1><br></br>
  {% for user in users %}
    {{ user.id }}
    {{ user.name }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

Total users: {{ count }}
```

Where *id* and *name* fields in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
{{ user.id }}
{{ user.username }}
{{ user.date }}
...etc...
```

Comment: Item "date" for "Array" does not exist in AcmeWebBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 5 and line5 in the template is: {{ user.id }} :/

Comment: You can do a {{ dump(user) }} and see what all array keys are available to you.

Comment: Thank you Roony i fox the problem.Thanks once again :)